# UIView animation downscale instantly hides the view

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiviewanimation, uiviewpropertyanimator

I'm trying to downscale a view like this :

```
func test() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        self.testView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 0)
    }
}
```

When I do this the view gets hidden instantly.

However if I set the Y scale to something close to 0 it works :

```
func test() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        self.testView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 0.00001)
    }
}
```

Any idea why I have this behavior ? Is there a cleaner way to achieve this ?

Edit: Found an article about it [here](https://medium.com/@sarthak.tayade/problem-when-animating-a-uiview-to-scale-to-zero-using-cgaffinetransform-on-ios-2f50717add18)